# How to get the status of angular $interval - check if the interval has been cancelled or not

Tags: angularjs, promise

I am new to Angular (and JS) and just a little confused.

I start a timer with :

```
var getOverviewMapTimer = $interval($scope.UpdateOverviewMap, UPDATE_FREQUENCY);
```

and, if I understand it, `getOverviewMapTimer` is a "promise".

I want to be able to check if the timer is running & had excepted that if I ever
`$interval.cancel(getOverviewMapTimer);` then `getOverviewMapTimer` would be `null` and I could check for that.

This seems not to be the case.

Do I have to explicitly destroy the promise (what goo is a promise to timer that has been cancelled?).? If so, how & would I then have to explicitly set it to `null`?

I *think* that I should use `cancel(getOverviewMapTimer);`, but am not 100% sure as `getOverviewMapTimer` is still non-null afterwards.

Thanks for your help

Comment: if you cancel the promise, I believe that it is not null, but still a promise, but a rejected one (maybe?). But if you want it to be `null`, you can do something like `getOverviewMapTimer = ($interval.cancel(getOverviewMapTimer)) ? null : getOverviewMapTimer;`

Comment: cancel(promise); Returns true if the task was successfully canceled

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After `var getOverviewMapTimer = $interval(...);` `getOverviewMapTimer` holds a reference to an object (that happens to be a promise).

Doing `$interval.cancel(getOverviewMapTimer)` passes (and cancels) the object referenced by the `getOverviewMapTimer` variable, but there is no way to convert an object to null. The `getOverviewMapTimer` variable will continue to hold a reference to the promise object and the only way to set it to null is through a new assignment (i.e. explicitely setting it to null):

```
var getOverviewMapTimer = $interval(...);
...
$interval.cancel(getOverviewMapTimer);
getOverviewMapTimer = null;
```

---

**Advanced Topic:**

It sounds indeed nice to have an easy way to find out if an interval-promise has been cancelled or not (e.g. adding a custom `cancelled` property to the promise object and setting its value to true when cancelling the interval).
Angular is cool enough to be incredibly flexible and extensible, so using the concept of a **[Service Decorator](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/object/$provide#decorator)** we are able to "augment" the `$interval` service, extending its `cancel()` method to add a `cancelled` property and setting its value to `true` when cancelling an interval-promise:

```
/* Service Decorators can be configured in `config` blocks */
app.config(function ($provide) {

    /* Register a decorator for the `$interval` service */
    $provide.decorator('$interval', function ($delegate) {

        /* Keep a reference to the original `cancel()` method */
        var originalCancel = $delegate.cancel;

        /* Define a new `cancel()` method */
        $delegate.cancel = function (intervalPromise) {

            /* First, call the original `cancel()` method */
            var retValue = originalCancel(intervalPromise);

            /* If the promise has been successfully cancelled,
             * add a `cancelled` property (with value `true`) */
            if (retValue && intervalPromise) {
                intervalPromise.cancelled = true;
            }

            /* Return the value returned by the original method */
            return retValue;
        };

        /* Return the original (but "augmented") service */
        return $delegate;
    });
});
```

Now, we can use the `$interval` service as usual and we can always check an interval-promise's `cancelled` property to find out if it has been cancelled.

```
var getOverviewMapTimer = $interval(...);
...
console.log(!!getOverviewMapTimer.cancelled);   // false
$interval.cancel(getOverviewMapTimer);
console.log(!!getOverviewMapTimer.cancelled);   // true
```

---

See, also, this **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/fZc3W/)**.

Comment: An excellent answer. You put so much work into it that would suggest that you forward it to the AngularJS team for future inclusion! Ever o/s which I have even used (and that's quite a few) will somehow "nullify" a timer reference when it is cancelled. This seems like an oversight.  Thanks again for your help

Comment: Nice answer!! (I am sure lots of people might not have found this when they were looking for same stuff)... I just updated the question title, so that this  answer comes on top on search. Feel free to update the question more to catch the attention of more eyes.. :)

Comment: However i thing you don't need to create a bound function for `$delegate.cancel.bind($delegate);` since no methods are being accessed from the context...

Comment: @PSL: Thx ! I always create bound functions (it's a mix of laziness and desire to be on the safe side). But, you are right; it's redundant here, so I removed the binding :)

Answer (score 2):

It's technically impossible that `getOverviewMapTimer` is `null` after calling `$interval.cancel(getOverviewMapTimer);`.

If you want it to be null you have to do it yourself. Either immediately after cancelling the interval or via callback:

```
if ($interval.cancel(getOverviewMapTimer)) {
  getOverviewMapTimer = null;
}
```

or

```
var getOverviewMapTimer = $interval($scope.UpdateOverviewMap, UPDATE_FREQUENCY);
getOverviewMapTimer.catch(function() { getOverviewMapTimer = null; });
```

Be aware, though, that the callback is asynchronous.

Answer (score 2):

easy

```
var interval = $interval(function() { }, 1000);
console.log(interval.$$state.status); //0

$interval.cancel(interval);
console.log(interval.$$state.status); //2

if(interval.$$state.status == 0)
    //valid
else
    //invalid
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that properties prepended with $$ indicates that the property is 'internal' and shouldn't be counted on in production apps.  I don't believe it would not be considered a breaking change to modify the behavior of this property in a future version.